# WCF: how to exchange data between instances?

Tags: wcf, security

I have a WCF service which supported SOAP and RESTful protocols.
My idea is to have a failover cluster with N instances of the WCF service in network.
All instances should synchronize some sensible data to provide clustering.
The question is: how WCF instances can exchange sensible data? 
How to prevent any 3rd spy application intervention between any of 2 my WCF services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use a load balancer between your WCF instances and the internet. This will handle the routing of request to the appropriate instance without you having to do any coding.

If all instances of the service connect to the same database and only get data from the database when they need to, then there's no need to pass information between the servers.

Comment: The matter is WCF requires from a client to login providing name/password, sqlserver_name, db_name. That info associates with some unique session id. This session id used by client to call methods. And this list:  id->[name/password, sqlserver_name, db_name] should be synchronized by my idea. In this case client can do login on one service and then call methods of any of other instances

Comment: @Oleg it's all handled by the load balancer. It's all done for you. You do per message authentication, which is all sorted once you login for the first time.

Comment: yes, but it is a specific of my WCF service: client calls method and provide session id, service retrieves user_name/pwd from memory array by this session id, does impersonation and connects to sql server. You see that every service instance should have this array and sync it

Comment: @Oleg this isn't an uncommon scenario so I would expect that a load balancer can be set up to handle this. I've only been involved in the case where there's a common connection to the database so I can't tell you exactly how it's done.